# Pytorch mask like Gluon npx.sequence_mask

Tags: nlp, pytorch, mask, gluon

I am trying to do this tutorial: https://d2l.ai/chapter_attention-mechanisms/attention.html but in Pytorch and I'm stuck in this function:

`npx.sequence_mask()`

I tried using torch.masked_fill and masked_scatter but to no success. Namely, I want:

`a = torch.randn(2, 2, 4)` 
`b = torch.randn(2, 3)`

and to get a result like `npx.sequence_mask()`
 [sequence_mask documentation](https://numpy.mxnet.io/api/deepnumpy/generated/mxnet.npx.sequence_mask.html)

```
 ([[[0.488994  , 0.511006  , 0.        , 0.        ],
    [0.43654838, 0.56345165, 0.        , 0.        ]],

   [[0.28817102, 0.3519408 , 0.3598882 , 0.        ],
    [0.29034293, 0.25239873, 0.45725834, 0.        ]]])
```

Could anyone help me out with any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this works, but any better solution?

```
def mask_softmax(vec, mask):
  leafs= vec.shape[0]      
  rows = vec.shape[1]
  cols = vec.shape[2]

  for k in range(leafs):
    stop = int(mask[k])
    for j in reversed(range(stop,cols)):
      vec[k, :, j] = torch.zeros(rows) #all rows of col i <-- 0

  vec = vec - torch.where(vec > 0, 
                          torch.zeros_like(vec), 
                          torch.ones_like(vec)*float('inf')) # switch 0 by -inf
  # softmax(-inf) = nan  
  for k in range(leafs):
    for i in range(rows):
      vec[k,i] = F.softmax(vec[k, i], dim=0)

  vec[vec != vec] = 0 # nan = 0

  return vec

# testing
a = torch.rand((2,2,4))
mask = torch.Tensor((1,3))
mask_softmax(a, mask)

>>> tensor([[[0.5027, 0.4973, 0.0000, 0.0000],
             [0.6494, 0.3506, 0.0000, 0.0000]],

            [[0.3412, 0.3614, 0.2975, 0.0000],
             [0.2699, 0.3978, 0.3323, 0.0000]]])
```

Answer (score 0):

d2l now provides an official PyTorch version, in which the following function is defined as equivalent to `npx.sequence_mask`:

```
def sequence_mask(X, valid_len, value=0):
    """Mask irrelevant entries in sequences."""
    maxlen = X.size(1)
    mask = torch.arange((maxlen), dtype=torch.float32,
                        device=X.device)[None, :] < valid_len[:, None]
    X[~mask] = value
    return X
```

Ref: https://d2l.ai/chapter_recurrent-modern/seq2seq.html#loss-function